# SQL returning NULL instead of empty result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2be8/6)

I am making a simple blog system where posts can have more than one category, so I have this query:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(item_category) AS item_categories
FROM (`dev_pages`)
LEFT JOIN `dev_items_to_categories` ON `dev_items_to_categories`.`item_id` = `dev_pages`.`page_id`
WHERE deleted_time IS NULL
AND `page_type` =  'blog'
AND `item_category` =  '16'
ORDER BY `page_title` ASC
```

It works fine but if there are no results instead of coming back as nothing it returns NULL or the default value (See SQL Fiddle)

I managed to make a around but I was wondering if anyone had a better solution to this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (

    SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(item_category) AS item_categories
    FROM (`dev_pages`)
    LEFT JOIN `dev_items_to_categories` ON `dev_items_to_categories`.`item_id` = `dev_pages`.`page_id`
    WHERE deleted_time IS NULL
    AND `page_type` =  'blog'
    AND `item_category` =  '16'
    ORDER BY `page_title` ASC

) AS a
WHERE page_id > 0
```

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY`. And any conditions on the `dev_items_to_categories` table should be in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(item_category) AS item_categories
FROM (`dev_pages`)
LEFT JOIN `dev_items_to_categories` ON `dev_items_to_categories`.`item_id` = `dev_pages`.`page_id` AND `item_category` =  '16'
WHERE deleted_time IS NULL
AND `page_type` =  'blog'
GROUP BY dev_pages.page_id
ORDER BY `page_title` ASC
```

You also need to put `item_category = '16'` into the `ON` clause. Otherwise, you will filter out rows with no matches in `dev_items_to_categories`; since you're using `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, I assume you want those rows with null matches.

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2be8/25)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me solve the problem, but the AND `item_category` =  '16' in the join didn't seem to do anything, but putting it as a where worked

Comment: But if you put it in the `WHERE` clause, then you won't get rows from `dev_pages` that have no match in `dev_items_to_categories`. The reason to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` is because you want those rows to appear in the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try coalesce function.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(coalece(item_category,'')) AS item_categories
FROM (`dev_pages`)
LEFT JOIN `dev_items_to_categories` ON `dev_items_to_categories`.`item_id` = `dev_pages`.`page_id`
WHERE deleted_time IS NULL
AND `page_type` =  'blog'
AND `item_category` =  '16'
ORDER BY `page_title` ASC
```